# Cast a sqlparameter into a DBNULL value if it's null

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I have a query that update a certain table inside my database in which I assign a parameter to it, this latter take value of a textbox.text if the value isn't null it works just fine, if it is, I get this error message "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object".

My question is, what type of casting should I use to avoid the use of If statement?

```
SqlCommand loadbonus = new SqlCommand()
loadbonus.Connection = conn;
loadbonus.CommandText = "UPDATE Client SET [Restant Bonus]=[Restant Bonus]-(SELECT SUM([Prix Total]) FROM Comptoir WHERE [N° Comptoir]='" + tabcontrol.SelectedIndex + "'),[Total Consommé]=[Total Consommé]+(SELECT SUM([Prix Total]) FROM Comptoir WHERE [N° Comptoir]='" + tabcontrol.SelectedIndex + "') OUTPUT INSERTED.[Restant Bonus] WHERE [Code Client]=@CodeClient";          
loadbonus.Parameters.Add("@CodeClient", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(clientcodecomptoire.Text);
```

Actual error message :

"When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object"

I have tried the following casting and it didn't work:

```
loadbonus.Parameters.Add("@CodeClient", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(clientcodecomptoire.Text)??DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid an `If`?   How can this code be producing an error about converting to DateTime?

Comment: because I have several sql paramaters like this one, it will save me less lines of codes

Comment: Are you sure that these are the lines that give the error?

Comment: @Steve, yes I'm sure, it's weird right! I have no Datetime data type for the related paramater field

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` will **never** return `null`, so `??` will never apply; are you sure the problem is what you think it is?

Comment: Note: tools like Dapper will always do the work to get this right, i.e. they know how to `null`-check inbound parameters correctly; if possible, I *strongly* recommend Dapper or similar (disclosure: I'm the primary author) - it is your friend if you're currently doing ADO.NET by hand

Comment: @Marc Gravell yes! I'm sure, how is that? well because I already tried it with an If statement (If (Textbox.text!=null) ) and it work just fine.

Comment: See also [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1268253.aspx?Method+design+handling+null+values+in+SqlParameter+) forum discussion.

Comment: @slimnaitseghir but you aren't asking whether `Textbox.text` is null... you're asking whether `Convert.ToInt32(...)` is null, which it never is - it returns `int`

Comment: It sounds like you mean: `.Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientcodecomptoire.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToInt32(clientcodecomptoire.Text);`

Comment: @MarcGravell thank's that worked just fine!

Comment: Why did you parameterize only a portion of your query?

Comment: @SeanLange the inputs that I didn't parameterize are not manually inserted input, so no worries about it.

Comment: But why not be consistent and always parameterize everything? Conditionally coding defensively is not a good habit imho.

Comment: But on the topic of your question, if you convert this to DBNull you will not get any rows returned because you are using = and NULL will never equal anything.

Comment: @SeanLange thank's for the effort and suggestions, about DBNULL value  yes! your are right, no rows will be updated and that's the point, it will only apply if you provide a valide input value.

Comment: @SeanLange any other suggestion for the repetition of this portion that I think you've noticed in the query "SELECT SUM([Prix Total]) FROM Comptoir WHERE [N° Comptoir]='" + tabcontrol.SelectedIndex + "'"

Comment: I would move this to a stored procedure. Then you can easily calculate sum once. It is generally accepted to be a better approach to software design to have layers anyway so this would be a good step in moving that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
int number;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(clientcodecomptoire.Text, out number);
loadbonus.Parameters.Add("@CodeClient", SqlDbType.Int).Value = success ? number : DBNull;
```

if it fails to cast the input string, the `number` would be `0`;

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I'd like to have a DBNULL value if my input is null.

Comment: You should not use the number output when TryParse returns false.